# PHP file downloaded instead of executed with nginx try_files

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, php-fpm

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, nginx 1.6.2, php 5.5.12. I have a site set up like this:

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/oliviataussig;
    index index.php;

    server_name oliviataussig.com www.oliviataussig.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

When I go to the homepage (index.php), it works fine. However, when I click on any of the links on the page (this is a WordPress-like CMS) I want to fall back to `/index.php`, and it does that, but `index.php` gets downloaded instead of executed. How do I fix that?

Comment: remove index.php from `location /` block

Comment: @HrvojeŠpoljar I did that, and then I get a 404 when accessing the menu links (e.g. http://oliviataussig.com/moving/). I want to fall back to `/index.php` since that script will handle the request and route everything appropriately. I don't want to give a 404.

Comment: that's because you're matching for `php$` . If some link is php with arguments and parameters afterwards it will not be matched by `php$`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. What is the solution, then? I'm looking at the "Proxy Everything" examples here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls (in the 'good' section), but neither of them is what I need. This is just a typical Wordpress-like pretty URLs situation.

Comment: Actually `/index.php` _should_ be in the first `try_files` but `=404` should not.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hrvoje suggested, Wordpres ->Nginx codex gives examples on most of possible situations (http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)

In your case, the config file should look like below:

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/oliviataussig;
    index index.php;

    server_name oliviataussig.com www.oliviataussig.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;


    # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this worked! I omitted the `/wp-admin` rewrite because this is actually an Indexhibit site, not Wordpress.

Comment: How would you get this working in a UserDir?

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to CLEAR THE CACHE of your browser to see results with the next line.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was driving me nuts until I followed your advice and cleared the cache. nginx had been behaving correctly for a while but the browser was stuck with a memory of a bad earlier interaction.